# Send securely a ConnectionString to DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, connection-string

I'm using EF 6.1 Code-First.

Currently my `DbContext` class look like:

```
public class StylishBlogDB : DbContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the StylishBlogDB class.
    /// </summary>
    public StylishBlogDB()
        : base("name=StylishBlogEF")
    {

    }
}
```

`StylishBlogEF` ConnectionString is located in my `app.config` file and with the login info (user and password).

I'm planning to remove my sensitive data from the connection string and get it from the user when my application being launched.

I developed a login form in WPF which takes all the needed info from the user. 
My form contains `TextBox` for user name and `PasswordBox` for password so it returns as an output two parameters: a `string` which hold user name and `SecureString` which keep the password.

So my question is:

How can I build a connection string from all the following parts:

1. string which holds all the connection string info without sensitive data
2. string which hold a userName
3. SecureString which holds a password

and send it as input parameter to `StylishBlogDB` class (inherits from DbContext)?

BTW - I'm using .Net framework 4.5

Comment: Have you seen this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738533(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @DavidTansey thx for your comment, I looked at this link but I didn't find how to provide the authentication details (user + pwd)?

Comment: Look here for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209754/set-entity-framework-connection-string-at-runtime